# How do I load the contents of a text file and display it in a SwiftUI Text view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm creating a new iOS app using SwiftUI and need to display the contents of a text file in a Text view.  I know how to load the contents of the file and store them in a string variable.  My problem is finding the correct place to put that code so I can reference it when I create the Text view.  Below is the code for the view that's hosting the Text view in question.

```
struct LicenseView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("") // How do I populate this with the contents of a text file?
            .navigationBarTitle("License")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Check In"){})
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding `var data: String?` to the struct and use `Text(self.data ?? "")`  ?

Comment: You should place that kind of code in a separated file, I would suggest using MVVM architecture

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope is helps. It used `Bundle.main` to fetch file and ScrollView to display long text.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: LicenseView(model: model)){ Text("License") }
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

struct LicenseView: View{
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text(model.data).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }.padding()
        .navigationBarTitle("License")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Check In"){})
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: String = ""
    init() { self.load(file: "data") }
    func load(file: String) {
        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "txt") {
            do {
                let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data = contents
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else {
            print("File not found")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, does this retain text formatting such as Bold and New lines, empty lines etc? If not is there a way to load a formatted text file?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a better solution using the above answer from NikzJon. This retains simple text formatings such as bold titles in the license file.

```
import SwiftUI

class TextFileReaderModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var data: LocalizedStringKey = ""
    
    init(filename: String) { self.load(file: filename) }
    
    func load(file: String) {
        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "txt") {
            do {
                let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data = LocalizedStringKey(contents)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else {
            print("File not found")
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct IntellectualPropertyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: TextFileReaderModel = TextFileReaderModel(filename: "licence")
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                        Text(model.data).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .navigationBarTitle("Legal Information")
                }
    }
}
```

finally create a Markdown version of your licence text file using a tool such as https://stackedit.io/app#  . Then add it as a text file to your XCode project. It will retain formattings.